# Enterprise Library 5.0 Connection Pool Timeout

Tags: asp.net, webforms, timeout, enterprise-library

I have an old web application written in ASP.Net 2.0 Web Forms. I use the Data Access Block in Enterprise Library and have recently updated to version 5.0. The application is tiered, ie, UI layer, Service Layer, Data Layer. It also uses SQL Server 2008 for the data storage.

I have recently noticed that the following error is appearing when I run the application and browse to particular pages.

**Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.**

This tends to happen on pages that do a lot of separate reads from the database, maybe up to as many as 20 on one page.

Below shows snippets of my Data Access Class.

```
Public Class DataAccess

    ' create a private instance of the database factory
    Private db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()

    Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal params() As SqlParameter, ByVal strSproc As String) As Integer

    Dim intReturnValue As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cmd As DbCommand

    cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(strSproc)
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 120

    For i = 0 To params.Length - 1
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, params(i).ParameterName.ToString, params(i).DbType, params(i).Value)
    Next

    db.AddParameter(cmd, "return_value", DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, "", DataRowVersion.Default, 0)

    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd)
    intReturnValue = Int32.Parse(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "@return_value"))

    Return intReturnValue

    End Function



    Public Function ExecuteDataReader(ByVal params() As SqlParameter, ByVal SProc As String) As SqlDataReader

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = Nothing
    Dim cmd As DbCommand

    cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(SProc)
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 120

    For i = 0 To params.Length - 1
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, params(i).ParameterName.ToString, params(i).DbType, params(i).Value)
    Next

    dr = TryCast(DirectCast(db.ExecuteReader(cmd), RefCountingDataReader).InnerReader, SqlDataReader)
    Return dr

    End Function
```

Throughout my code, once I have finished with an SqlDataReader I always do something like this

```
If Not (drSource Is Nothing) Then
   drSource.Close()
End If
```

Is there anything you folk can see that I am missing? Does it look like my code could be leaking connections or not closing properly?

I always thought the Garbage collector got rid of any open connections.

Any feedback or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is closing the data reader, but not the data connection associated with it.

Since your data reader is a `SqlDataReader`, it has a `Connection` property.  You should be able to use that to close and dispose of the connection.